# Creating a object session in Meteor

Tags: session, meteor

I am designing a meteor app that includes user session management and rooms sessions. I was wondering how am I able to create this room session that can be accessible anywhere in the app. I am thinking about something like Meteor.room with analogy with Meteor.User. At the moment a user login into a room, I am looking for a way to use this object anywhere to assign other features specifically to it regardless of the user session.

Comment: how you define session..?? is this the same as http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session ..??

Comment: Part of, Session in Meteor is a global object on the client only. Is there a way to use it everywhere ?

Comment: You want to access certain data that can be accessed anywhere in you app..??

Comment: I guess I will need to reformulate my question. How can I create a session on the server similar to Meteor.userId by assigning a new global variable. An example would be Meteor.currentRoom with all the records of the room that the user is currently using. 
My use case is: A user creates an account, he then create a new room or log into an existing room. From that point any new created object from any feature will have as foreign key the creator (which is the currentUser, Meteor.userId) and the currentRoom (Meteor.currentRoom). Thanks :)